# How can i return NSError in a Objective c like completionBlock of a function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In swift i want send NSError in a method completion block like in objective c.

Comment: Your question is misleading. Do you want answer in `Swift` or `Objective-C`? Your question title says one and your question detail says another.

Comment: `title says one and [question] says another` tagged as both. (I'd probably not tag [objective-c], make [swift] the 1st tag, not mention swift in the title and ogle the result to decide whether to (fully) hyphenate *Objective-C-like*.) (Please capitalise as best you can (the personal pronoun *I*, for one). (Use a spelling checker.) In the title, the indefinite article `a` precedes something pronounced starting with a vowel: I'd use *an*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) is same as objective c block. you can try this:

```
func myFunc(withCompletionHandler completionHandler:((NSError?) -> Swift.Void)?){
        var error:NSError? = nil
        //DO YOUR TASK AND ASSAIGN ERROR TO var error

        completionHandler?(error)
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i just need that :)